# How to query a column of a custom content type using Content Search?

Tags: content-query-web-part

How to query a column of a custom content type using Content Search? It is a date column and I would like to search Today+7 (today till the next 7 days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following these steps.

- Map the site columns in your custom content type with any of the available refinable properties. if its a date column map it with refinabledate properties e.g. "RefinableDate00" or "RefinableDate01" available in search schema.
  Here is a good link to get you started.
  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/06/19/stage-14-configure-refiners-for-faceted-navigation/#HowToMap

   Note: To locate the crawled property in this step, you need to ensure that there is at least some value for that site column associated in any content in your site.
- Once the mapping is done, please wait until the next incremental search crawl is completed.
- After that you can query for your content type in the search. E.g. if you have mapped for property RefinableDate01 to your site column, you can operate on search queries like RefinableDate01 = TODAY or RefinableDate01 < TODAY etc